# PGFPlot equally spaced coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

how can i make the plot that the provided x-coordinates are separated visually with the same distance.

So instead of 0 500 1000 1500 2000 there should be

0 10 20 50 100 200 ...

and the second thing is that the ylabel and the y-coordinates overlap, how to move the label further out?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Züge(\#),
        ylabel=Zeit(s)]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (10,25)
        (20,12)
        (50,33)
        (100,1800)
        (200,1800)
        (500,1800)
        (1000,509)
        (2000,1514)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: you can use `symbolic x coordinates` such that every coordinate is mapped to an integer.

Comment: ok i tried it but it does not display all symbolic coordinates

Comment: thank you ok with axis x line=left it display all coordinates now what about the label?

Comment: @user3613886 10 20 50 100 200 500 ... looks to me like log scale.

Comment: @user3613886 Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/itvl3.png ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use log scale in conjunction with user defined ticks and tick labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xlabel=Züge(\#),
    ylabel=Zeit(s),
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000},
    extra x tick labels={10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000}]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (10,25)
      (20,12)
      (50,33)
      (100,1800)
      (200,1800)
      (500,1800)
      (1000,509)
      (2000,1514)
    };
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]